# Need help to setup svn along with xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, macos, ios5, tortoisesvn, xcode4.2

I am trying to setup svn along with xcode 4.2.
I have a team of 4 programmer and want to keep our proj repository on someone's machine.
so that all 4 programmers can sync the master copy on their mac.

Is it possible? How could I achieve it? What are steps involved to get this?

can anyone suggest me the step by step solution?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Subversion, then follow any set of directions for installing Subversion. Xcode is not involved.

Having said that, Xcode comes with Git built-in, so you may wish to consider using that instead of Subversion.